# if i close the flutter will the stream still be running?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a stream builder for an api to let me know about any new data, will it stop updating me if I close the app? if so , how do I keep it running even after closing the app ?

Answer (score 0):

No if you close your app then no one stream is running because it is not any background service .
so when your app will be close stream will be destroyed also.

if you want to run it even after your app closes you have to use background services.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, can you please tell me what are those background services ? @Jay Limbani